# How to get text inside an XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

How do I get the text that is within an XmlNode? See below:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("descendant::*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    XmlNode node = nodes.Item(i);

    //TODO: Display only the text of only this node, 
   // not a concatenation of the text in all child nodes provided by InnerText
}
```

And what I ultimately want to do is preppend "HELP: " to the text in each node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to iterate over all the direct children of the node (using `ChildNodes`) and test the `NodeType` of each one to see if it's `Text` or `CDATA`. Don't forget that there may be multiple text nodes.

```
foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
{
    if (child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text ||
        child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
    {
        string text = child.Value;
        // Use the text
    }
}
```

(Just as an FYI, if you can use .NET 3.5, LINQ to XML is a *lot* nicer to use.)

Comment: `ChildNodes` is an `XmlNodeList` which implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`.  Therefore you need to be explicit about the type of `child` in the loop above - i.e. `foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)`.

Answer (score 3):

Search the node's children for a node with `NodeType` of `Text`, and use the `Value` property of that node.

Note that you can also select text nodes with XPath by using the `text()` node-type test.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the InnerText property of xmlnode
read `node.InnerText`

Comment: The comment in the code explicitly says the OP *doesn't* want to get the concatenated text within all child nodes, which is what InnerText does.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. See the documentation: "Gets or sets the **concatenated** values of the node and all its children."

Answer (score 1):

Check this

also you might check what options you get when you write "reader."

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<ISO_3166-1_List_en xml:lang="en">
   <ISO_3166-1_Entry>
      <ISO_3166-1_Country_name>SINT MAARTEN</ISO_3166-1_Country_name>
      <ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>SX</ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>
   </ISO_3166-1_Entry>
   <ISO_3166-1_Entry>
      <ISO_3166-1_Country_name>SLOVAKIA</ISO_3166-1_Country_name>
      <ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>SK</ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>
   </ISO_3166-1_Entry>
</ISO_3166-1_List_en>
```

and reader really basic but fast

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("c:/countryCodes.xml");
      List<Country> countriesList = new List<Country>();
      Country country=new Country();
      bool first = false;
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
          case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
            if (reader.Name == "ISO_3166-1_Entry") country = new Country();
            break;
          case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            if (first == false)
            {
              first = true;
              country.Name = reader.Value;
            }
            else
            {
              country.Code = reader.Value;
              countriesList.Add(country);
              first = false;
            }                       
            break;          
        }        
      }
      return countriesList;
```