# How do I get an xml node text?

Tags: c#, xml, text

I have an xml file with nodes containing codes that I need to get into a string, if the suffix selected matches the one in the xml.
This is how my xml looks like:

```
<ntcode NTCODE="BTM">
"2","724,02F,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FF","724,03F,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FF" </ntcode> 

<ntcode NTCODE="CLR">
"1","724,05F,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FF" </ntcode>
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(@"/*network address*/\NTCodes.xml");
            XmlNodeList list = xml.SelectNodes("ntcodes/ntcode");
            string ntcode = null;

            foreach (XmlNode node in list)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["NTCODE"].Value.ToString().Equals(suffix))
                {
                    // what should I put here?
                }
            }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text inside an XmlNode (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266647/how-to-get-text-inside-an-xmlnode-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wedded to `XmlDocument`?  This is pretty trivial with the much nicer LINQ to XML API:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path\NTCodes.xml");

var value = (string)doc.Descendants("ntcode")
    .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("NTCODE") == suffix);
```

If you wanted to stick with your `XmlDocument` code, the text from your found `XmlNode`, the value can be retrieved by:

```
var value = node.InnerText;
```